# Lisp variable using itself in definition

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I am building a window application in Lisp using the LTK library. I want a button that does an action and, possibly, hides itself. However, this code:

```
(let* ((left (button 0 0 f "←" #'(lambda ()
                                   (decf start page-length)
                                   (funcall redraw)
                                   (if (>= start page-length)
                                       (ltk:configure left :state :visible))
                                       (ltk:configure left :state :hidden))))))
```

claims that "left" is an undefined variable (the rest is defined in code beyond the scope of this problem).

Worst case scenario, I avoid the "button" function I wrote and rework the code for this particular situation, but the scenario begs a general solution. Is there any way in Lisp to use a variable in a function in the definition of the variable?

Comment: Is `letrec` what you're looking for?

Comment: @psmears Seems to be, but I need its equivalent in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `let*` with only one binding is the same as a `let` binding. A `let` binding does not exist until the body is executed. During the execution of `button` the reference for `left` must be from an earlier closure or global as `left` is created after the expression is evaluated. You can do this:

```
(let ((left nil))
  (setf left (button 0 0 f "←" #'(lambda ()
                                   (decf start page-length)
                                   (funcall redraw)
                                   (if (>= start page-length)
                                       (ltk:configure left :state :visible)
                                       (ltk:configure left :state :hidden))))))
```

NB: There was a bug in the `if` such that the lambda always would execute `(ltk:configure left :state :hidden)`

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth here is a version of `letrec` in CL:

```
(defmacro letrec (bindings &body decls/forms)
  (assert (and (listp bindings)
               (every (lambda (b)
                        (or (symbolp b)
                            (and (consp b)
                                 (symbolp (first b))
                                 (null (cddr b)))))
                      bindings))
      (bindings) "malformed bindings")
  (multiple-value-bind (names values)
      (loop for b in bindings
            collect (etypecase b
                      (symbol b)
                      (cons (first b)))
            into vars
            collect (etypecase b
                      (symbol nil)
                      (cons (second b)))
            into vals
            finally (return (values vars vals)))
      `(let ,names
         (psetf ,@(loop for name in names
                       for val in values
                       collect name
                       collect val))
         (locally
           ,@decls/forms))))
```

Then

```
> (letrec ((x (lambda (y)
                (if (null y)
                    'done
                  (funcall x (cdr y))))))
    (funcall x '(1 2 3)))
done
```

Comment: perhaps s/`psetf`/`setf`, to better fit the Scheme semantics? (also, you've let one `car` slip through, instead of the `first` :) ). also, a Scheme coder would normally expect to be able to tail-call the `letrec`-defined function, and CL has no TCO guarantee... I'm not sure how/whether this could be mitigated (or whether it even should be mitigated).

Comment: I've changed the `setf` to `psetf`: thanks.  For `car` / `first`: I use `first`/ `rest` when I'm thinking about a list and `car` `cdr` when I'm thinking about pairs.  But I've not been consistent here for sure: `car` for the name of a binding and `second` for the value: it should either be `first` & `second` or `car` and `cadr`.  Not sure which!  For TCO I just treat CL as if it did and don't use implementations which don't!

Comment: first, second, and rest - about lists; car/cdr - about cons cells/pairs; makes sense. seeing both car and first refer to the same thing is ...  weird. :)

Comment: @WillNess: I've changed it as you're clearly right.  The thing which was derailing me (after having forgotten how it worked) is that the sanity check at the start really does need to use `cddr` because it's trying to check for a 2-elt list but doesn't want to use `length` (may fail to terminate, may raise exception) or `list-length` (may raise exception).  CL needs a safe pattern-matching library (I'm sure there is one in Quicklisp, but I did not want some huge dependency for the macro) like Racket has.